# cURL and download tor browse git

Tags: windows, git, curl, github, tor

Can someone advise me how to use cURL to download tor browser git?
https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/tree/?h=tor-browser-60.2.1esr-8.5-1
https://git.torproject.org/tor-browser.git

This: tor-browser-60.2.1esr-8.5-1

Thx.

Comment: What do you want to download? Git repository? Why curl and not git?

Answer (score 0):

curl can't download and unpack git repositories over https or ssh.  You will need to use the git client unless they offer a zip archive of the master branch of http/https.

If you're trying to clone the repo over Tor, use `torsocks` in conjunction with git:

```
torify git clone http://dccbbv6cooddgcrq.onion/tor-browser.git
```

Then checkout whatever branch or release you are interested in working with.